# Compilation error: Redefinition of union name

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, posix, mutex, unions

I have this piece of code here and I get a GCC error: Redefinition of union semun right at the beginning of this code

```
union semun {
    int              val;    /* Value for SETVAL */
    struct semid_ds *buf;    /* Buffer for IPC_STAT, IPC_SET */
    unsigned short  *array;  /* Array for GETALL, SETALL */
    struct seminfo  *__buf;  /* Buffer for IPC_INFO
};
```

This program is about communicating with mutexes. I don't think that it's about the other parts of the program because the error comes here, right at the first line of it, and this code is outside the main, at the beginning of the program so there's not any other union declaration before (and after). Thank you

Comment: Since you believe ecatmur's answer to your question is right, you can help the SO community by [marking it accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Then it doesn't keep showing up as unanswered. In addition, ecatmur will gain some reputation points if you do so, and so will you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to X/Open, some platforms define `union semun` in their headers (specifically in `sys/sem.h`).

You can check accordingly using appropriate platform identifier macros:

```
#if (defined(__GNU_LIBRARY__) && !defined(_SEM_SEMUN_UNDEFINED)) \
    || defined(__FreeBSD__) || ...
/* union semun is defined by including <sys/sem.h> */
#else
union semun {
    // ...
};
#endif
```

If you have a meta-make system for your package (configure, CMake, etc.) you might check for the existence of `union semun` at the configure stage instead of relying on platform checks.

Comment: OK thanks a lot! It seems that this union is already included with <sys/sem.h>. Thanks for the quick tip!

Comment: I also worked this program with Linux Mint and the union wasn't included in sys/sem.h. Now on FreeBSD it is. So the best way is to put ifs at the beginning.

Comment: @STRATOSpeed yes, you probably want to use `#if defined (__FreeBSD__)`  etc.